# Questions about returning char* and memory

Tags: c

I just watched a tutorial on functions that return char*. In the tutorial, this function printed pest, however, when I run this on my computer, it does not print anything.
I'm wondering if this is because since the stack memory of s[] has disappeared, does the string stored at s[] also disappear. Thus, in the main function, string is just an empty pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getstring(){
    char s[] = "test";
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* string = getstring();
    string[0] = 'p';
    printf("%s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the tutorial in question?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8IkGIqZoLQv @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Please don't watch any more tutorials in that series. What they show is *undefined behaviour* as `s[]` no longer exists when the pointer to it is used. So you are correct in saying "the stack memory of s[] has disappeared".

Comment: @WeatherVane okay thank you very much. Is it bad practice to use functions that return char*?

Comment: Some library functions return a pointer to `static char str[]` and that persists (is not on the stack), for example `char *asctime()`. Other functions return `char *` to point to data supplied by the caller, for example `char *strchr()`. Others allocate the memory dynamically, such as the non-standard `char *strdup()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see, I'll try to learn more about those functions.

Comment: ...so the bad practice, is when the pointer returned is to an object which does not exist. In some cases, your example might "appear" to work, but that's just bad luck.

Comment: @WeatherVane: What specifically do you object to in the video? I did not watch the whole thing, but the presenter says that returning `str` after `char str[] = "test";` is improper, as `str` vanishes. It is not the presenter’s fault OP used the code that was said to be incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It was just confusing when he said that it was improper, but it still worked for him.

Answer (score 0):

The `s` is invalidated when returning from `getstring()`, but the returned pointer `string` doesn't become empty. The value of the pointer is unchanged, but you must not dereference the pointer after returning. It is not easy to distinguish this kind of invalid pointer with valid pointer, so you must be careful.

Comment: so since string = getstring(), which is the invalid pointer s, this makes string pointing to the same place as s, but it is also invalid?

Comment: Re “The value of the pointer is unchanged”: Per the C standard, the value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the lifetime of the object it points to ends (C 2018 6.2.4 2). One reason for this is that a pointer might not be just a memory address but may use auxiliary data structures, and the auxiliary data may change when an object’s lifetime ends and its memory is released, and then merely using the value of a pointer can cause traps or other strange effects.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the compiler creates an array of chars sufficient to keep your string. The problem is, that it is allocated on the function stack which disappears after return from the function. A name of an array used in such a context is its address. It gets returned, but the memory it points to is invalid after return.

```
char* getstring(){
    char s[] = "test";
    return s;
}
```

In the following example, the string is allocated in a globally accessed space (pointer declaration is the key).

```
const char* getstring(){
    const char s* = "test";
    return s;
}
```

In the above example, location of the string will be accessible even after return from the function.

However, in this case you should not try to modify it. It is supposed to be a constant.

To make it a non-constant you should allocate memory space for it yourself and copy the string there:

```
char* getstring(){
    char s* = malloc(strlen ("test")+1);
    strcpy(s, "test");
    return s;
}
```

Do not forget to `free(string)` after you done with using it.